# SQLException thrown on await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync google+

Tags: authentication, model-view-controller, google-plus, google-oauth

I am trying to implement google+ authentication on my MVC5 app but am struggling to get it working on my live environment.

I have generated new keys for me live site from google apis and deployed the code.

I have set anonymous authentication for my site in iis8 on my server.

When I click the Google+ login button for the first time, I get to the sign in page and can click accept. The process then waits and waits until finally it fails. The second time round, I don't get the google login, but again get loads of waiting until it fails.

The code is failing on this line with a SQLException:

```
var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
```

"A network related or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to the SQL server".

Now as far as I can see with that line of code, I am not trying to connect to my SQL environment. So is this connecting to google to validate? Do I need some firewall ports or IP's opened on the server?

In IIS Express on my local, everything works fine!!

Many thanks

Comment: Vote close:  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to give accurate advice based on your description, but i had about same issue after installed new web app template in Visual Studio (thats how i come here). Probably you forget to change computer name in your web-config/connectionStrings or you dont have sql server installed.